# searching php with "0" is considered empty

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select, pdo

```
<select id="casenature" name="" class="InputBox">
  <option></option>
  <option value="0">Criminal</option>
  <option value="1">Civil</option>
</select>
```

This is my html of select and i get the value like

```
var casenature = $("#casenatureoption:selected").val();
```

and i send it via ajax to php. I receive it in php like

```
$casenature = $_POST['casenature'];
```

When i try to echo the value they are ok. I get `1` or `0` depending on the selected option

```
if (!empty($casenature)) {
     $q .= "t1.case_nature LIKE :casenature";
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);
     $stmt->bindValue(':casenature', "%" . $casenature . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
}else{
      echo "Empty";
}
```

My question is why do i get empty when i select the option with `value 0` i get empty ? If i select the option with `value 1` code is ok

Comment: You could make it a little more specific. `$casenature || $casenature === '0' `

Comment: Reading the manual on `empty` would have told you that already.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset` and not `!empty` then tell me what happened

```
if (isset($casenature)) {
     $q .= "t1.case_nature LIKE :casenature";
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);
     $stmt->bindValue(':casenature', "%" . $casenature . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
}else{
      echo "Empty";
}
```

UPDATE:
The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)

0 (0 as an integer)

"0" (0 as a string)

NULL

FALSE

array() (an empty array)

var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) the example number 1 will clearly tell that `if (isset($var)) {` is to be used

`UPDATE`

With @jeroen explanation i would suggest to use the condition below.

`$casenature === '0' || $casenature === '1'`

Comment: Sorry, but `$casenature` will always be set, since the above assignment does that. You probably want to test for `$_POST['casenature']` instead?

Comment: When it's in_POST I believe 0 is a string but it will still be considered empty.

Comment: i think the update will be sufficient enough to let us know that the `0` in the `post` is empty

Comment: No, `isset()` can tell you if the form was submitted or not, but if the value of the variable on the submitted form is `""` (an empty string), `isset()` will return `true` while the OP needs `false` as none of the two values was selected.

Comment: @jeroen i see what you are trying to say now thank you for the wonderful explanation.then i would go with the comment of DanielM to be the best fit. But let me says that i think there is never be a `''` since the value is from select maybe if it is from input box. correct?

Comment: @HogRider Not selecting any option and submitting the form will get you an empty - set - string.

Comment: yeah didnt think of that scenario :) thank you for clarify i learn alot :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behaviour of empty, please see [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). You can use `isset` or `array_key_exists` to check for the existence of a value.

Because `$casenature` will always be set you might have more luck with this though:

```
if ($casenature || $casenature === '0') {
     $q .= "t1.case_nature LIKE :casenature";
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);
     $stmt->bindValue(':casenature', "%" . $casenature . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
} else {
      echo "Empty";
}
```

Using tripple equals `===` in PHP (and JavaScript) means "exactly equal to". This checks for type as well as its loose value. So for example `'1' !== 1`, the string `'1'` is not exactly equal to the integer `1` even thought they are loosely equal, because one is a string and one is an integer. PHP and JavaScript are both loosely typed languages because this is more valuable on the internet because normally everything you receive will lack type information and therefore be considered a string.

I've never found `empty` to be helpful in real world applications as it's doing almost the same thing as evaluating an expression to false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid automatic typecasting problems (`0 == false == '' == null`, etc.) so there are 2 things you need to check for:

- See if `$_POST['casenature']` is set / the form was submitted with the variable included;
- If it is, `$_POST['casenature']` will be a string so you could use for example `strlen()` to see if the length of the string is greater than `0`.

You could of course also make sure that the ID's of your items start at `1` instead of `0` which will probably be the case anyway if the ID's come from a database.

Comment: Sir OP said `When i try to echo the value they are ok. I get 1 or 0 depending on the selected option`. So i am guessing that the `$_POST` is really set php just recognize it as `empty` as the manual says please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You can use `array_key_exists` to check if `$_POST` has a particular value. You can also use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see everything inside of it. It's best to dump the output of those in `<pre>` tags because, unless you install something like Xdebug, they won't contain html formatting and just come out as one long line ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '0';
var_dump(empty($string)); // boolean true
```

replace

```
if (!empty($casenature)) {
```

to

```
if ($casenature !== '') {
```

But i recommend :

1. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php
2. Use sequence 1,2,3... instead of 0,1,2...